# MATLAB Finding the number of data points within confidence intervals

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have a set of data in Matlab, a matrix 6256x48, that I have found the mean, std dev, and CI intervals for. This was done using:

```
[muhat1,sigmahat1,muci1,sigmaci1] = normfit(data);
```

My question is, how can I find the number of results or data points in each column of the original data that are within the confidence intervals within the `muci1` array.

The `muci1` array is 2 rows of 48 points, the top row being the lower bound and the bottom row being the upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = rand(6258,48); %//data
[A,B]=size(data); %// size of your data
[muhat1,sigmahat1,muci1,sigmaci1] = normfit(data); %//stats of your data

mask(A,B)=0; %// create output mask
for ii = 1:B
    mask(:,ii) = data(:,ii)<muci1(2,ii)&data(:,ii)>muci1(1,ii); %// fill mask
end
FinalResult = sum(mask,1); %// number of points within CI per column
finalresult2 = sum(FinalResult); %// number of points within all CIs total
```

The `for` loop searches for entries in each column that are between the two bounds as given by `muci1`. If a number is between the bounds it gets a `1` in the `mask`, otherwise it becomes a `0`.

Comment: Finally, to get the numbers form `mask`, use `sum`

Comment: @Daniel, how do you use sum to get numbers from mask?

Comment: @Adriaan sorry my mistake